# Composite primary key in phpmyadmin not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

[image]

I am using username,level as primary keys but when i try to insert data as:

```
username     level
sj            1
sj            2
```

It displays duplicate entry error.
I think it is not treating them as single primary key.

Comment: According to the image, `time` is a primary key.  Also, why is a column called `time` stored as a string instead of a native date/time type?

Comment: I can't see the picture clearly, but it seems like you have unique index on your username.

Comment: No,you are interpreting it wrong,username and level are primary key.

Comment: @frz3993 maybe you are right,I recreated table and now everything is working fine.